# Where do i get the AccessToken from SharePoint

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sharepoint

i need to know, how to upload file to share point using react, i open the docs,

here's the link that i read:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=http
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery
3. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/upload-documents-show-documents-in-a-page-using-sharepoint-rest-api

and there's REST code looks like this:

```
GET https://{site_url}/_api/lists/getbytitle('{list_name}')/items
Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
```

so my question is, how to get the `accessToken`? is it possible to get accessToken if i didn't login with microsoft account?

Comment: You should read up on REST and OAuth before attempting this. The HTTP sections are requests that you have to make in order to do something.

Comment: Hey, thanks @Jeroen for your comment, is there any config in sharepoint that i need to configure? i really didn't know where to start with this share point (upload file)

To be honest, i pretty know about REST, and still learning OAuth